# Passing a class instance to session in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I created a custom class in my view and tried to add it to the session using this code:

```
request.session['class_instance'] = Custom_Class()
```

Each instance of this class store an authorization code which I use to generate new access code to call API. It's something like this:

```
class Custom_Class():

def ___init___(self, auth_code):
    self.auth_code = auth_code

def refresh(self):
    param = {'auth_code': self.auth_code}
    r = requests.post("https://API, param)
    return r.json()
```

Django raise an error:

Object of type user_authorization is not JSON serializable

When I replace the class with an integer, it works fine and I can get it in other views.

Is it possible to pass a class in Session to be available in different apps?

Comment: What is your class? What are you trying to do with it? You shouldn't try and create your own authentication in Django.

Comment: It's not about authentication. I have a class that call another API based on a custom field in a table linked to user and generate a token for Oath access to that API. I need this class to generate a new token every time I'm going to call that API using the authorization code of that specific user.

Comment: OK but you still need to show more detail about the class. Probably, you just need to store the token in the session, and recreate the class only when needed.

Comment: I added more details on the class. The auth_code is unique for each user and I want to store it in the instance of class so that each time, I just call the refresh() method of the class to get the refresh code to make API calls.